# heroku asset clean error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

this is the error while trying to clean asset

```
Running `rake assets:clean` attached to terminal... up, run.5619
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:       EOFError (EOFError)
Backtrace:   /home/love/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:246:in `readline'
             /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:43:in `block in start'
             /home/love/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
             /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:31:in `start'
             /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:113:in `rendezvous_session'
             /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:100:in `run_attached'
             /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:21:in `index'
             /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
             /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.35.0/bin/heroku:17:in `<top (required)>'
             /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/heroku:23:in `load'
             /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku run rake assets:clean
Version:     heroku-gem/2.35.0 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3
```

`what should i do, to sove this problem?

Comment: Report it, looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run `heroku run rake assets:clobber`? This removes all assets instead of leaving the 3 most recent ones [(source)](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails#rake-task).